# Is there a way to export Flutterflow code to flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the free version of Flutterflow and I'm trying to copy paste the code manually (as exporting requires premium). However, I'm skeptical because some import statements require flutterflow packages, which I can't directly download. Is this going to be a problem? Is there any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these files are 100% needed in order to build your flutter app. It is part of the business model of FlutterFlow to hide the source code for these modules.

In the free version of FlutterFlow, it is not possible to view or download these dependencies. So sadly, there is no comfortable way. I assume that FlutterFlow would intentionally like to keep you away from reproducing these dependencies in order to grow their business model.

During my research, I stumbled upon the GitHub project [`FlutterFlow/flutterflow-ui`](https://github.com/FlutterFlow/flutterflow-ui) which claims to provide the missing dependencies. You can install it via the pub.dev package [`flutterflow_ui`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterflow).

You could install it by adding this to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutterflow_ui: ^0.1.0+4
```

However, I have no information on the authenticity and license of this package. So be careful when adding it to your project. You will also need to replace all the relative imports `../flutter_flow/..` after installation.

Comment: Well it actually comes from flutterflow itself. You can also see that from the name of the project ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can view code of a file in Free tier and copy & paste it .It wont be completely work because you won't have the other files that are being imported in this file, you can modify but it will costmore time and effort.

check flutterflow community answers for more details. [flutterflow community](https://community.flutterflow.io/)